# how to show customized data report in window form applications

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I'm developing an App in C# window form applications and I've a table as

```
Have

ID | name | value | day | stage | creation_date
1     1st    20     Mon    1
2     2nd    30     Mon    2
3     3rd    15     Tue    1
4     4th    10     Wed    3
5     5th    25     Thu    4
6     6th    15     Fri    1
7     7th    10     Fri    2
8     8th    30     Sat    3
9     9th    20     Sat    1
10    10th   20     Sun    4
```

Now I want to do some statistics as

```
Want

Mon       Tue       Wed       Thu      Fri      Sat      Sun
1st-20$    3rd-15$  4th-10$   5th-25$  6th-15$  8th-30$  10th-20$
2nd-30$                                7th-10$  9th-20$
```

every stage represents a unique color that i want to put as the background color of the correspondence table cell.

example

```
1 -> green
2 -> orange
3 -> grey
4 -> yellow
```

I attached a picture below to demonstrate what I want to show on my statistics form

[image]

I'll filter by **from** and **To** and want my table to show the data accordingly along with the background color of stage.

This is what I've done this far

```
 public partial class Report : Form
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();
        public Report()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            table.Columns.Add("Monday", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Tuesday", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Wednesday", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Thursday", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Friday", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Saturday", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Sunday", typeof(string));

            var Monday = db.Tables.Where(x => x.Week == "Monday").Select(x=> x ).ToList();
            var Tuesday = db.Tables.Where(x => x.Week == "Tuesday").Select(x => x).ToList();
            var Wednesday = db.Tables.Where(x => x.Week == "Wednesday").Select(x => x).ToList();
            var Thursday = db.Tables.Where(x => x.Week == "Thursday").Select(x => x).ToList();
            var Friday = db.Tables.Where(x => x.Week == "Friday").Select(x => x).ToList();
            var Saturday = db.Tables.Where(x => x.Week == "Saturday").Select(x => x).ToList();
            var Sunday = db.Tables.Where(x => x.Week == "Sunday").Select(x => x).ToList();

            ReportTable.DataSource = table;

        }

    }
```

I'm having trouble of adding data to my rows by

```
table.Rows.Add("Monday data", "Tuesday data", "Wednesday data", "Thursday data", "Friday data", "Saturday data", "Sunday data");
```

Because I can't put foreach for every seven of the lists and then set the background according to stage.

Comment: What did you try so far ? It looks like a very basic job

Comment: Do not ask other to do homework for you. We will only help you if you have real code problem.

Comment: @AleksaRistic Thanks for help.I can attach datagridview to set and attach buttons to do basic crud but I'm having trouble in creating custom columns. Kindly can you provide any good link for that.

Comment: @zackraiyan I've updated my question.

Comment: i'll take a look now

Comment: @Azeem112 `ReportTable` is your datagridview?

Comment: @AleksaRistic yes Report Table is the name of my datagridView.

Comment: One more question because i need to test out how fast is this method, how many rows you need to be displayed? Is it around 100-200 or around 1k or more than 10k?

Comment: @AleksaRistic I just developed it and there are less then 100 records but in future size can be increased to 10k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code as a solution

```
            var Monday = db.JobTables.Where(x => x.Day == "Monday").Select(x => x).ToList();
            int Monday_count = db.JobTables.Where(x => x.Day == "Monday").Count();

            var Tuesday = db.JobTables.Where(x => x.Day == "Tuesday").Select(x => x).ToList();
            int Tuesday_count = db.JobTables.Where(x => x.Day == "Tuesday").Count();

            var Wednesday = db.JobTables.Where(x => x.Day == "Wednesday").Select(x => x).ToList();
            int Wednesday_count = db.JobTables.Where(x => x.Day == "Wednesday").Count();

            var Thursday = db.JobTables.Where(x => x.Day == "Thursday").Select(x => x).ToList();
            int Thursday_count = db.JobTables.Where(x => x.Day == "Thursday").Count();

            var Friday = db.JobTables.Where(x => x.Day == "Friday").Select(x => x).ToList();
            int Friday_count = db.JobTables.Where(x => x.Day == "Friday").Count();

            var Saturday = db.JobTables.Where(x => x.Day == "Saturday").Select(x => x).ToList();
            int Saturday_count = db.JobTables.Where(x => x.Day == "Saturday").Count();

            var Sunday = db.JobTables.Where(x => x.Day == "Sunday").Select(x => x).ToList();
            int Sunday_count = db.JobTables.Where(x => x.Day == "Sunday").Count();

            int max_1 = Math.Max(Math.Max(Monday_count, Tuesday_count), Wednesday_count);
            int max_2 = Math.Max(Math.Max(Thursday_count, Friday_count), Saturday_count);
            int MAX = Math.Max(Math.Max(max_1, max_2), Sunday_count);


            String[,] array = new string[MAX, 7];

            for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
            {
                array[i, 0] = "";
                array[i, 1] = "";
                array[i, 2] = "";
                array[i, 3] = "";
                array[i, 4] = "";
                array[i, 5] = "";
                array[i, 6] = "";

                if (Monday_count > i)
                    array[i, 0] = Monday[i].Job_Number +" -- "+ Monday[i].Job_Value +"$";
                if (Tuesday_count > i)
                    array[i, 1] = Tuesday[i].Job_Number + " -- " + Tuesday[i].Job_Value + "$";
                if (Wednesday_count > i)
                    array[i, 2] = Wednesday[i].Job_Number + " -- " + Wednesday[i].Job_Value + "$";
                if (Thursday_count > i)
                    array[i, 3] = Thursday[i].Job_Number + " -- " + Thursday[i].Job_Value + "$";
                if (Friday_count > i)
                    array[i, 4] = Friday[i].Job_Number + " -- " + Friday[i].Job_Value + "$";
                if (Saturday_count > i)
                    array[i, 5] = Saturday[i].Job_Number + " -- " + Saturday[i].Job_Value + "$";
                if (Sunday_count > i)
                    array[i, 6] = Sunday[i].Job_Number + " -- " + Sunday[i].Job_Value + "$";

                table.Rows.Add(array[i, 0], array[i, 1], array[i, 2], array[i, 3], array[i, 4], array[i, 5], array[i, 6]);
            }

ReportGrid.DataSource = table;
```